# Load html template after async http.get call is done

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have routing config in my main app.js.

```
// app.js
angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/company-list.html',
        controller: 'CompanyListCtrl as companyListCtrl'
    }).when(...
```

Although in the app.js I have a directive that renders an image as a background css element of the template's div.

```
/app.js 
// Directives
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('backImg', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var url = attrs.backImg;
            element.css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')',
                'background-size': 'cover'
            });
        };
    });
```

CompanyListCtrl controller dependent on an http Service that makes a call to a server and returns data. That data contains 'url' for the directive above.

```
 //controllers.js
 angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('CompanyListCtrl', ['CompanyService', function (CompanyService) {
            var self = this;
            self.companies = [];

            CompanyService.getCompanies().then(function (response) {
                self.companies = response.data;
            });
        }]);
```

My 'company-list.html' template with the directive renders before async data is returned. I guess I need to use 'resolve' in the route config however, what is the dependency should be there when $htt.get call is implemented as an external service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the resolve option:

> resolve - {Object.=} - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of
>   these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to
>   be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the
>   values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess
>   event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the
>   $routeChangeError event is fired. The map object is:
>
> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the
>   controller. factory - {string|function}: If string then it is an alias
>   for a service. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and the
>   return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise,
>   it is resolved before its value is injected into the controller. Be
>   aware that ngRoute.$routeParams will still refer to the previous route
>   within these resolve functions. Use $route.current.params to access
>   the new route parameters, instead.

```
angular.module('myApp', ["ngRoute"])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/company-list.html',
        controller: 'CompanyListCtrl as companyListCtrl'
        resolve: {
            companies: ['CompanyService', '$route', function(CompanyService, $route) {
                return CompanyService.getCompanies($route.current.params.companyId).then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                }
            }]
        }
    }).when(...    


angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('CompanyListCtrl', ['companies', function (companies) {
            var self = this;
            self.companies = companies;


        }]);
```

Comment: if I have $routeParams.companyId that I want to add to CompanyService.getCompanies($routeParams.companyId) do I need to add dependency like companies: ['$routeParams', 'CompanyService' ... and controller logic similar to the original ansver?

Comment: Inject $route and use $route.current.params.companyId.  I will update the answer